# Geometry problem inspired by the masonic square and compass symbol

Tags: geometry

Let $AB = AC, AB \perp AC, H$ point such that $AH$ is the bisector of the angle $BAC$ and $BHC = 45^{\circ}$. Find the length of $AH$.

I am sure this problem is easy, but I have not been able to solve it. I realize we can deduce lot's of information about angles. Any hints or solutions are welcome.

Some story on the problem:

I had seen the masonic square and compass symbol (https://www.freemason.com/masonic-symbols-square-compasses/) and considered it to be nice-looking. So I decided to try to construct it. When trying to construct it however, I was immediately faced with the difficulty of what should the length of the line segment AH be ,with H having the very specific properties described in the problem. I thus formulated the above geometrical problem. I wrote it down, drew a shape and tried solving it with no success. I had noticed we knew a lot about angles and that we should therefore use that knowledge, maybe even bring a few lines. Nonetheless I could not find the solution. That led me to post the problem here which received one great solution which I completely understood and wrote down analytically. I would, however, like to see other approaches on this problem.

Comment: What is the length of $AB$ ?

Comment: the length of AB is x.

Comment: Draw the figure, and use the law of sines to determined $AH$.  $AB$ is opposite an angle of $22.5^\circ$, and $AH$ is opposite an angle of $(180^\circ - 45^\circ - 22.5^\circ) = 112.5^\circ$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Draw the figure as shown. Here $ABDC$ is a square.

We can deduce that $\angle CHD=\angle DHB=\angle HBD=22.5^{\text o}.$

Hence

$$AD=\sqrt 2 x$$
$$DH= DB=x$$

$$AH=AD+DH=(\sqrt 2 +1)x$$

Comment: Great! I do not understand however ∠=∠=∠=22.5o. Could you elaborate?

Comment: First prove that $\Delta ABH \cong \Delta ACH$ (SAS). This implies that $\angle CHD=\angle BHD=\frac{45^{\text o}}{2}=22.5^{\text o}$. Note that $\angle ADB=45^{\text o}$. By exterior angle of triangle, $\angle HBD=22.5^{\text o}$